# Permission Check for REST API Endpoint Runs Twice?

Tags: plugins, rest-api

I'm making a plugin using the WP REST API, and everything seems to be working as expected. However, there is behavior I don't understand. The `authPermissionCheck()` method is executed **twice** for each request before output is generated - first [here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/d9f222f74045f67a3f9a330c8d1ace77456720d8/wp-includes/rest-api/class-wp-rest-server.php#L913) and then [here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/d9f222f74045f67a3f9a330c8d1ace77456720d8/wp-includes/rest-api.php#L617). It just seems inefficient. Does anyone understand why?

Here's the relevant portion of my plugin code (stripped down):

```
class My_REST_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action( 'rest_api_init', function()
        {
            $this->user = wp_get_current_user();

            register_rest_route( 'myplug/v1', '/auth', array(
                array(
                    'methods'  => \WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
                    'callback' => array( $this, 'authenticate' ),
                    'permission_callback' => array( $this, 'authPermissionCheck' )
                )
            ));
        });
    }

    // This method is called twice when the
    // auth endpoint is hit. Why?
    public function authPermissionCheck()
    {
        if ( ! user_can( $this->user, 'read' ) ) {
            return new \WP_Error( 'rest_forbidden', esc_html__(
                'No permission.', 'my-text-domain' ),
                array( 'status' => 401 )
            );
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I came across your question when searching for a solution to mine. My permission callback is being called 4 times.

Comment: keep in mind the alternative is to call it once and put it somewhere in memory which requires extra infrastructure, whereas the call itself is meant to be super super fast and just logic, if this is slowing down your site in any measurable way then something is very wrong. IMO this is micro-optimising

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, it's by design.

https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/2400

Permission callback is run once for the `Allows` header, and the second time for the callback itself.

Didn't dug enough through it to understand why :/